# When and why to send an email notification of password reset

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-reset

[The Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Notify-users-via-email-when-their-passwords-change) states that "For security purposes, sometimes you need to notify users when their passwords change." In general, when would you need to provide such notification, and why?

Answer (score 3):

At most websites I use, especially for my 401(k), I get an e-mail every time I change my password changes.  Given that it is something that affects my financial future, I appreciate that so I know right away if the password were to change and I didn't initiate that.

In respond to your question, it depends.  For a website that just wants people to log in for some reason (such as a pizza place that doesn't store my credit card info or address), it may not be a big deal to notify people of a password change.  For anything with privacy or security issues, such as medical, financial, IT security, anything to do with minor children, or other such systems, I'd say that notification of all password changes, immediately, would be mandatory.  For code repositories, I'd want to know if someone is logging in as me so I can prevent theft of my company's or my personal intellectual property. For that I'd send a notification of a password reset so the user could ensure that code being uploaded/downloaded by them is being done from the appropriate repository.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your system. If your password reset occurs through a generated email link it serves no purpose sending another email after.

If the password is changed  through an application interface the user should be notified. Old credentials could have been used to access the app or brute forced access.

Informing a user involves them within the security of their own account and helps detect behavior you may miss.

There are no compliance requirements I'm aware of for this mechanism but anything that gets users bring responsible for their security is a good thing.

Comment: When you state "If your password reset occurs through a generated email link..." are you including the case where they receive a password reset email, click the link in it, and input the new password via the application interface?

Comment: Sorry yes that was what I meant - a forgotten password feature basically opposed to an update password feature that occurs after a user authenticates